# FileSystemWatcher events raising twice despite taking measures against it

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I've browsed quite a few threads on here and on other sites for solutions to this problem.

Here's my FileMonitor class:

```
class FileMonitor
{
    public FileMonitor(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher()
            {
                Path = path,
                IncludeSubdirectories = true,
                InternalBufferSize = 65536,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };

            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileCreated);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileDeleted);
            watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnFileRenamed);
            watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnWatcherError);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private void OnWatcherError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ((FileSystemWatcher)sender).EnableRaisingEvents = false;

            LogFileSystemChanges(e);
        }

        finally
        {
            ((FileSystemWatcher)sender).EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnFileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ((FileSystemWatcher)sender).EnableRaisingEvents = false;

            LogFileSystemChanges(e);
        }

        finally
        {
            ((FileSystemWatcher)sender).EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnFileDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ((FileSystemWatcher)sender).EnableRaisingEvents = false;

            LogFileSystemChanges(e);
        }

        finally
        {
            ((FileSystemWatcher)sender).EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnFileRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ((FileSystemWatcher)sender).EnableRaisingEvents = false;

            LogFileSystemRenaming(e);
        }

        finally
        {
            ((FileSystemWatcher)sender).EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }

    private void LogFileSystemChanges(FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string log = string.Format("{0:G}: {1} | {2}", DateTime.Now, e.FullPath, e.ChangeType);
        Console.WriteLine(log);
    }

    private void LogFileSystemRenaming(RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        string log = string.Format("{0:G}: {1} | Old name: {2}", DateTime.Now, e.FullPath, e.OldName);
        Console.WriteLine(log);
    }
}
```

As you can tell, I have tried the "lock" of `((FileSystemWatcher)sender).EnableRaisingEvents = false;`, but I can tell from my console output my events are triggering twice.

Any ideas on this? I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Three weeks have passed but you still didn't follow-up. Did you solve the problem? Can you vote an answer, please, or tell us how you solved it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found a solution. I kind-of gave up upon realizing how many problems many people have had with the FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem and after much ado came to the conclusion that *Notepad* writes a file three times (!) in row. If an app really saves that much often (maybe to triangulate backups and such) there isn't much you can do.

I also noticed you have attached to all events, you should narrow it down to the least you need and filter out those you aren't interested in with the [NotifyFilters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Perhaps a new file is written with a new name, the old file is deleted and then the new file is renamed to the old file name? Would this raise 3 write events?

Comment: Yes, it is also possible that the `*.txt` file is renamed to `*.bak`, a new `*.txt` file is created and then the backup is deleted. This would also raise 3 events on the folder. Substitute the txt/bak extensions with whatever you use. It totally depends on the program that is used.

Comment: I think that approach is used in MFC at least - disk events are plentiful and difficult to deal with.

Comment: Maybe someone should start a github project implementing a wrapper leveraging this `leaky abstraction` and adding best practices control code to make it work in a more useful way, with higher level events, timeouts, fallback on polling and whatnot... those typical workarounds you often see on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried to use the **FileSystemWatcher** class before (many years ago it turns out - 2008), and experienced major problems. It is a **[leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)** at best. I reported my findings back then on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15656/Advanced-FileSystemWatcher). Look for "Glytzhkof" in the comments list. As I recall I had problems with just about every aspect of the class, but **it might have been improved now after so many years**.

In summary my experience back in the day was that events disappeared altogether or piled up causing exceptions based on variables such as whether a disk's write cache was enabled, whether RAID, NAS or regular disks were accessed, and other random hardware issues that I do not recall exactly. Interestingly it seems it worked with UNC paths. No idea why. Mapped drives failed.

Have a look at the [summary in the Code Project discussion](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15656/Advanced-FileSystemWatcher). I am sure there are improvements since I tried it out, and a few new bugs perhaps :-). It seems disk storage hardware is hard to deal with as a high level abstraction - [it leaks](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html). Personally I ended up scanning for files manually using a service and regular disk functions. I wasted a lot of time before doing things manually.

**UPDATE**: See new info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704476/129130

Comment: +1 on all you say, I've had the same experience with this. Furthermore, it seems to depend on the format, too. UNC on NTFS works but an UNC to a non-NTFS drive or even worse non-Windows... doesn't work more than it does. I understand that without any support on the controller/driver/format side it's impossible to implement, so to make this work a total hardware/driver/protocol support is needed across platforms. That's not something you can suppose to have easily. Still, I use it when I need it. It's very useful until... it stops working :)

Comment: I've taken a look at your CodeProject! I'd +1 you again if I could :) Excellent work! That's what I meant with my previous comment.

Comment: regular polling will have the very undesirable side effect of re-spinning up the disks. espcially in `laptop-mode`. or, preventing spin down altogether because of the timer being shorter than spin down delay. This is just wrong™