# get filesystemwatcher events to occur on main UI thread

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

Can i get filesystemwatcher events to occur on the main UI thread ?. Currently file changes are fired off on their own threads.

Comment: WPF or WinForms? WinForms use `Control.Invoke()`, WPF use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` from your event handler to pass the event off to your UI thread.

Comment: winforms - what i mean is a change event - not how do i update the GUI

Comment: You don't have to update the GUI, but the controls know what thread they're on, and this will get some code to execute on that thread. What you do is up to you.

Comment: @steve you are correct. Do you want to add as an answer so i can accept?

Comment: Go with Hans Passant's answer - I was unaware of this solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply set the [FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to the form instance.  Same thing as calling BeginInvoke() but done automatically for you.  Boilerplate code:

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    fileSystemWatcher1.SynchronizingObject = this;
}
```

Comment: It is a one-liner, hard to see the problem you have with it.

Comment: thanks Hans - i think alot of people will benefit from your wisdom

Comment: If you add the FileSystemWatcher in the designer, the SynchronizingObject is set automatically in the code behind file.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => SomeMethod())); // Check files in the Main thread otherwise threading issues occur
```